# How to apply group_concat in Splunk SPL

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, splunk-dashboard

[image: emphasized text]

I want to implement a group_concat-like behavior in Splunk.Here as in the table where serviceA has 2 entries which need to be combined with a delimiter and the count needs to be added. Is there any way we can achieve the functionality using SPL. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!!

Answer (score 3):

```
... | stats count, values(Status) by Service_Name
```

You need to create a multi-value field and [`values()`](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/9.0.3/SearchReference/Multivaluefunctions#values.28X.29) will be an appropriate way to do it in your case

Answer (score 1):

To combine the Status values with comma separators, add these commands to your query.

```
| stats count as Count, values(Status) as Status by Service_name
| eval Status = mvjoin(Status, ",")
```